# Angular header component that includes logo component

Tags: html, css, angular

I have two components: header and logo and I want the logo inside of the header. Currently I don't have any significant code for the header component which is intentional because there is nothing else that needs to go inside of it besides the logo right now.

I need help on how to include the logo inside the header component. The logo is the child of the header.

Here is my stackblitz code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vo4y44?file=src%2Flogo.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in logo.component.ts you have the selector (app-logo), you can use  `<app-logo />` in other components.

Edit: don't forget to add "LogoComponent" in your app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

To include the logo inside the header component in an Angular application, you need to follow these steps:

Step 1: Create the Header Component
First, create the header component if you haven't already. In Angular, you can use the Angular CLI to generate a new component. Open your terminal or command prompt and navigate to your project's root directory, then run the following command:

```bash
ng generate component header
```

This will create a new folder named `header` inside the `src/app` directory with the necessary files for the header component.

Step 2: Add the Logo Image
Place your logo image file (e.g., `logo.png`) inside the `assets` folder of your Angular project. The `assets` folder is typically located in the `src` directory.

Step 3: Modify the Header Component HTML
Open the `header.component.html` file located inside the `header` folder you created earlier. In this file, you can include the logo image using the `img` tag.

```html
<!-- header.component.html -->
<header>
  <!-- Add the logo image using the img tag -->
  <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
</header>
```

Step 4: Styling the Header (Optional)
You can add CSS styles to the header to control its appearance, position, and other properties. You can do this by adding styles directly to the `header.component.css` file or by using Angular's `styles` property in the component decorator.

For example, in `header.component.css`:

```css
/* header.component.css */
header {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Step 5: Use the Header Component
Now that you have created the header component with the logo inside it, you can use this component in other parts of your application. For example, if you have a main app component where you want to include the header, open its HTML file (`app.component.html`) and add the header component tag.

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<app-header></app-header>

<!-- Other content of your application -->
```

Make sure to import the header component in the `app.module.ts` file if you haven't done it automatically using the Angular CLI.

That's it! The logo should now be included inside the header component, and you can use the header component in other parts of your Angular application.